# NSJSONSerialization doesn't parse this JSON

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, nsdictionary, nsjsonserialization

I'm trying to parse this JSON that looks to me like well written, but `NSJSONSerialization` doesn't think the same AFAIK since it's returning an `NSArray`.

This is my code:

```
NSData* gamesData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:
                        [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://s42sport.com/polarice/json/games.json"]
                        ];

    NSDictionary* json = nil;
    if (gamesData) {
        json = [NSJSONSerialization
                JSONObjectWithData:gamesData
                options:kNilOptions
                error:nil];
        NSLog(@"%d",json.count);
    }
```

The questions are,

What's wrong with the JSON? Why NSSerialization doesn't return me the NSDictionary?

Edit: Yes, I just learned about the [...] vs {...}. Thank You.

Comment: That JSON is an array. There is nothing wrong except for your expectation that it is a dictionary.

Comment: check out my code suerly work for you...

Comment: looks like you didn't put in much effort in looking at even basic JSON syntax.

Comment: @hawk my code solve his requirement.

Comment: @JitendraDeore my comment was directed at the original poster.

Comment: the referenced file no longer exist, next time put the actual json text instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parse your `json` by this way.

```
NSURL * url=[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://s42sport.com/polarice/json/games.json"];

NSData * data=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

NSError * error;

NSMutableDictionary * json=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:&error];

NSLog(@"%@",json);

NSArray * array1=[json valueForKey:@"c"];

NSLog(@"%@",array1);
```

Try this code. this will surely work for you.

Comment: Yep, that worked, because of options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves?

Comment: Can I ask, what's the difference in the code? You make it return a NSmutableDictionary now. I thought it would return a NSMutableArray

Comment: no problem whatever you want you can get NSMutableArray depend upon requirement.

Answer (score 1):

NSDictionnary should be used for Object whereas NSArray is use for JSON array

```
NSArray* json = nil;
if (gamesData) {
    json = [NSJSONSerialization
            JSONObjectWithData:gamesData
            options:kNilOptions
            error:nil];
    NSLog(@"%d",json.count);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The JSON file you listed is an array (it starts and ends with a square bracket) so Objective-C reflects that with an NSArray root object.